# Problema con autocreación de tablas con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, dom, html-tabla

Estaba yo intentando parsear un JSON hacía una tabla HTML dinámica (que haga tantas filas como sean necesarias pero mismas columnas, siempre 2)

Para ello, desde el JS le paso este código (es posible que sea una aberración, pero hoy por hoy no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo de manera más sencilla):

```
document.getElementById('tablerepos').innerHTML  += "<tr>"  +   "<td class='repo'> " +  "<img src='images/logo.png' id='iconsIMG'> "  + json[i].name + "</td>" + " " ;
document.getElementById('tablerepos').innerHTML  +=  "<td class = 'repo'>" +  "<img src='images/fork.png' id='iconsIMG'> "  + json[i].forks + " <img src='images/star.png' id='iconsIMG'> " + json[i].stargazers_count + "</td>" + "</tr>";
```

Tengo una tabla creada, nada complicado:

```
<table id="tablerepos" border= "2">

</table>
```

La cosa está:  Para empezar abre un `<tr>`, luego un `<td>` luego pone la imagen y la info, luego cierra `td`. Esto la primera línea.

La segunda línea, abre otro `<td>`, pone imagen, pone info, pone imagen, pone info y luego cierra `td` y `tr`.

Si todo fuera como creo que tiene que ir, haría una tabla (que ya está creada) con 2 columnas y N filas, dependiendo de las veces que se ejecute el `for` (es dinámico, dependiendo de X).

El resultado es este:

[image: Problema Creacion de Tabla]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me crea los `tbody` por amor al arte, aunque la verdad no sé si eso influye. 
¿En qué me estoy equivocando? ¿Es posible hacer lo que quiero hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontraste la solución, voy a intentar explicar por qué ocurre eso y cómo podrías haberlo evitado de otra manera usando las funciones de JavaScript para manipulación del DOM.

Lo primero que tienes que tener en cuenta es que en las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador **cuando inspeccionas un elemento, no ves el código generado sino el código que el navegador está interpretando (que puede o no coincidir con el código real)**.

El problema viene (como ya averiguaste) al hacer la modificación en dos pasos y ocurre porque, **aunque el código que añades a la tabla puede ser correcto como un todo, no lo es cuando se divide por partes**. El navegador trata de ayudarte corrigiendo esos errores (interpretando qué es lo que querías hacer) y eso causa mayores problemas. Y el misterio de los `tbody` que aparecen se explica de igual manera.

El código que compartes es simple:

```
document.getElementById('tablerepos').innerHTML  += "<tr>"  +   "<td class='repo'> " +  "<img src='images/logo.png' id='iconsIMG'> "  + json[i].name + "</td>" + " " ;
document.getElementById('tablerepos').innerHTML  +=  "<td class = 'repo'>" +  "<img src='images/fork.png' id='iconsIMG'> "  + json[i].forks + " <img src='images/star.png' id='iconsIMG'> " + json[i].stargazers_count + "</td>" + "</tr>";
```

En la primera línea se añade a la tabla una etiqueta de apertura de fila con una celda dentro, y en la segunda línea se añade una celda más y se cierra la etiqueta de fila.

Ahora vamos a ver cómo interpreta el navegador eso (más o menos):

1. Se ejecuta la primera línea de código

   1. Se añade una etiqueta de apertura de fila (`<tr>`)
   2. Se añade una celda (abriendo y cerrando sus etiquetas con `<td>` y `</td>`)

      <sup>Aquí termina tu código y el navegador empieza a renderizarlo</sup>
   3. El navegador se da cuenta que falta una etiqueta de cierre de fila (`</tr>`) y la *añade* automáticamente para que el HTML sea correcto.
   4. El navegador se da cuenta de que tienes una fila en una tabla pero no está dentro de un `tbody` y *añade* un `tbody` a la tabla con tu fila dentro. Esto no es obligatorio, pero parece que Chrome lo hace para seguir una estructura específica.
2. Se ejecuta la segunda línea de código

   1. Se añade una celda (abriendo y cerrando sus etiquetas con `<td>` y `</td>`)
   2. Se añade una etiqueta de cierre de fila  (`</tr>`)

      <sup>Aquí termina tu código y el navegador empieza a renderizarlo</sup>
   3. El navegador se da cuenta que tienes una celda y que está fuera de una fila, así que *añade* una etiqueta de inicio de fila (`<tr>`) para que el HTML sea correcto y esa etiqueta coincide con la de cierre de más tarde.
   4. El navegador se da cuenta de que tienes una fila en una tabla pero no está dentro de un `tbody` y *añade* un `tbody` a la tabla con tu fila dentro.

Espero que se entienda bien, puede no ser una descripción 100% correcta de cómo interpreta la página el navegador, pero sirve para dar una idea aproximada de cómo lo hace y por qué ocurre lo que ocurre... y por qué vas a seguir teniendo el "problema" de los `tbody` que aparecen de la nada (algo que sigue ocurriendo incluso cuando has puesto todo el código en una línea).

---

Ahora, sé que es muy simple y rápido hacer `innerHTML`, pero te voy a poner otro método usando funciones de manipulación del DOM y de tablas con las que obtendrías el mismo resultado:

```
var tabla = document.getElementById('tablerepos');
var fila = tabla.insertRow();
var celda1 = fila.insertCell();
celda1.innerHTML = "<img src='images/logo.png' id='iconsIMG'> " + json[i].name;
var celda2 = fila.insertCell();
celda2.innerHTML = "<img src='images/fork.png' id='iconsIMG'> " + json[i].forks + " <img src='images/star.png' id='iconsIMG'> " + json[i].stargazers_count;
```

He hecho un poco de trampa porque el contenido de la celda lo estoy poniendo con `innerHTML` cuando podría hacerlo también con `createTextNode` y `appendChild` y sería algo más largo.

La idea es la misma y funciona sin los inconvenientes explicados antes. Además, si te fijas al inspeccionar elementos, verás que ya no se "crean" múltiples `tbody`, ahora el navegador sólo pondrá uno y añadirá las filas de `insertRow` todas en el mismo `tbody`.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, solucionado.

He puesto todo en una linea tal que así:

```
document.getElementById('tablerepos').innerHTML  += "<tr>"  +   "<td class='repo'> " +  "<img src='images/logo.png' id='iconsIMG'> "  + json[i].name + "</td>" + "<td class = 'repo'>" +  "<img src='images/fork.png' id='iconsIMG'> "  + json[i].forks + " <img src='images/star.png' id='iconsIMG'> " + json[i].stargazers_count + "</td>" + "</tr>";
```

y aquí el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código no es ninguna aberración, tranquilo, pero Javascript tiene la funcionalidad DOM que deberías mirarte, es una característica de Javascript con la que puedes modificar el cuerpo del html y no es complicado. Un saludo.